# Another mysterious frame identification

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage

I've got another mystery at my hands. This time this 26.6mm seatpost (although i'm not with a paquimeter on my hands, a 26.8mm one almost fits is), italian thread bb. By scratching the dropouts I couldn't find any visible stamps and I have no idea of any components and fork that it came originally. I can read the serial number as 903273 and have never seen those lugs before, does anyone have any idea?

[here are the pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKOyq.jpg)

Comment: It would be better if you included the pics in the post

Comment: My guess is that it's a bike frame.

Comment: The one thing you notice is that the lugs are "sculpted".  This is generally the mark of a better quality lightweight frame, though I suppose it's possible that a builder might use this as a way to fake better quality.

Answer (score 1):

The lugs don't look familiar. It has horizontal dropouts and full length brake cable housing so that dates it to sometime prior to the mid-80s. The fork is 100% not original to the frame. It has bottle braze-ons so it's likely made sometime after the mid-70s. The one peculiar thing is that it has bottle braze-ons but not shift lever braze-ons (and this bike most definitely predates integrated brake/shift levers such as STI or Ergo) It also has brazed on cable guides for the derailleur cables. I'm guessing the dropouts are 126mm spacing?

It could well have been made for a 26.8 post. That rattle can paint job could be compromising the fit and it's also not unusual to have the seat tube become slightly ovalized due to over heating the seat lug during assembly.

Comment: Horizontal dropouts and full length brake cable housing continued until after the mid 80's.  Do you mean mid 90's?  I think the missing shifter braze-ons are because it originally came with a stem shifter.  it looks like a fairly low end frame to me.

Comment: Yeah, it was more around '90 that horizontal drops quickly became the exception rather than the norm on production bikes due to indexing. 

Definitely a low end frame.